# How to migrate post from wordpress.stackexchange.com to stackoverflow

Tags: support, migration

I believe my [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82105/sidebar-widget-to-show-popular-post-not-working) is not getting much attention here. Is it possible to migrate post from here to stackoverflow ?

I searched the flag option but cant find anything thr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always [flag your own posts for moderator attention](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/privileges/flag-posts). We can then migrate the question. However, you asked that question just 54 minutes ago, and most of our members live in a time zone where it is early morning now. So … some patience doesn’t hurt.

And your question is on topic here. We will not migrate it to SO.

[Respect the community – your own, and others’](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/) explains why.

Comment: very true...have to keep patience(really dont know how I be too impatient today and totally agree its not off topic..will surely going to keep it here) thanks for the comments :)

Answer (score 0):

Wait: so as of this moment, you asked your question **7 hours** ago (hint: the *middle of the night in the US, where most WPSE members live*), and then **6 hours** ago, you were asking about how to migrate your question, because it wasn't receiving enough attention?

Seriously? **One hour**, and you want your question migrated?

If you need support that quickly, you don't need your question migrated; you need to find some paid support somewhere.